# Is one who only keeps Rabbinic laws he agrees with a Apikores?

Tags: heresy, non-rabbinic-judaism

There is a world famous Jewish speaker who believes in Torah Misinai and the like but only keeps the Rabbinic laws that make sense to him. For example, he does not keep Yom Tov Sheini in Chutz La'aretz. Would someone like that be considered a Apikores?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71193/discussion-on-question-by-eliyahu-is-one-who-only-keeps-rabbinic-laws-he-agrees).

Answer (score 3):

According to the Rambam the category of Epicurus includes those who "dispute [the authority of the Oral Torah's] spokesmen" (Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Teshuvah 3:8).  It is very difficult to argue that one who rejects the Rabbinic authority to enact binding legislation in direct opposition to their professed authority isn't disputing the spokesmen of the Oral Torah.

[Mishneh Torah, Teshuvah 3:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911896/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Three.htm)

Comment: How does this apply to the OPs case? I don't see anything in the question about authority

Comment: The distinction you wish to make, that this individual could conceivably recognize their authority but break it in a systematic fashion, is asinine.

Comment: Your enthymemes are misleading.

Comment: (Also using a fancy word for 'stupid' isn't any more acceptable as regards the Be Nice policy.)

Comment: The Rambam lists this individual as a Kofer, and with his examples of Tzaddok and Baisus he seems to imply that this is referring to derashos rather than d’Rabbanans. -1 for inaccurately portraying the Rambam as saying something he doesn’t.

Comment: @DonielF, Fair enough, I noted the use of the term kofer but didn't catch that it had actually  started a new topic.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Notice back in 3:6 that he lists all of the different categories that he’ll be subsequently expounding upon. It is a valid question that’s bothered me for some time why indeed he lumps together Apikores and Kofer into the same Halacha rather than splitting them into two separate ones. (Same question can be asked on 3:11.)

Comment: @DonielF Note that the Mechon Mamre edition splits 3:8 and 3:11 of the usual printed editions, each into two _Halakhot_, [3:16-17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1503.htm#16) and [3:20-21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1503.htm#20) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud's own definition of the term is one that denigrates a talmid chacham so I would think that there is no greater denigration than publicly flouting their laws.

Bavli Sanhedrin 99b:

> The mishna teaches that those who have no share in the World-to-Come include an epikoros. Rav and Rabbi Ḥanina both say: This is one who treats a Torah scholar with contempt.

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of "heresies" in Judaism. The terms apiqores, kofer, mumar, min, etc. denote different ideologies and thought processes, but are often today colloquially referred to as "apiqorsuth" or "kefirah". With that caveat in mind, rejecting the Oral Law is indeed considered to be heretical from the vantage of traditional rabbinic Judaism. The Rambam categorizes it as a type of kefirah b'torah (denial of the Torah). In H. Teshubhah 3:8[17] he writes:

> שלושה הן הכופרים בתורה:  האומר שאין התורה מעם ה', אפילו פסוק אחד,
> אפילו תיבה אחת--אם אמר משה אמרו מפי עצמו, הרי זה כופר בתורה; **וכן הכופר
> בפירושה, והיא תורה שבעל פה, והכחיש מגידיה, כגון צדוק ובייתוס**; והאומר
> שהבורא החליף מצוה זו במצוה אחרת, וכבר בטלה תורה זו, אף על פי שהיא
> הייתה מעם ה', כגון הנוצריים וההגריים.  כל אחד משלושה אלו כופר בתורה.
>
> There are three individuals who are considered as one "who denies the
> Torah": a) one who says Torah, even one verse or one word, is not from
> God. If he says: "Moses made these statements independently," he is
> denying the Torah. b) **one who denies the Torah's interpretation -
> that is the Oral Law, or disputes its transmitters as did Sadoq and
> Baytus.** c) one who says that though the Torah came from God, the
> Creator has replaced one mitzvah with another one and nullified the
> original Torah, like the Hagarenes and the Christians. Each of these
> three individuals is considered as one who denies the Torah.

Accordingly a person who "only keeps the Rabbinic laws that make sense to him" is categorized as a Kofer b'Torah. This person is rejecting the rabbinically transmitted perush (explanation of the Torah) and the authority by which it comes down. Such a stance is what the Karaite heresy historically argued for, echoing its early predecessors Sadoq and Baytus. That it did not have a problem with the idea of rabbinic interpretation per se - but felt that such interpretation was not authoritatively binding. That a person may reason independent of the Oral Law and come to a contrary and practiced conclusion. This movement was roundly condemned as heretical by rabbinic Judaism throughout history, and this view continues to be deemed a type of kefirah (denial).

Comment: It's very hard to equate disagreeing with the oral Torah and disagreeing with Rabbinic enactments. Just because both are terrible and both are arguments with things that you are likely to hear from a Rabbi does not make them the same things.

Comment: @Eliyahu rabbinic enactments are an aspect of תורה שבעל פה (the Oral Torah)

Comment: Thanks. I always viewed them as two different things, with Torah Sheba'al Peh having the force of a De'oraysa and Rabbinic enactments only being Miderabanan. Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: @Eliyahu It is a Hazalic term that encompasses everything passed down by tradition that was not written in the Torah, it includes many subdivisions (including legislated decrees and enactments). To learn more about all of it, I suggest learning the Rambam's introduction to the Mishnah (not to be confused with his intro to the Mishneh Torah). You can find it here: https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah?tab=contents

Answer (score -2):

In the strictest sense an Apikoro is a Jew who apes Goyim to the detriment of Judaism. It was coined after Jews who among other things would surgically try to reverse their Brit in the Seleucid Era. They would grease their bodies & then prace nude around the Temple Mount as they engaged in exercises.

A Jew who observes Mitzvot that they personally agree with is not an Apikoro. They are merely hypocrites & their hypocrisy of course does not escape G-d.

It is impossible for any one Jew to meet all 613 Mitzvot. Some are gender-specifuc. Some are Temple-specific. Observance is simply doing one's best to meet the huge & glorious onus of the Torah.